# Как правильно вывести многомерный массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть вот такой многомерный массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и есть скрипт который выводить этот массив

```
foreach($array[orders] as $dataraw) {   
    foreach($dataraw[basket] as $raw = ) {  


echo $dataraw[customer][given_name] ;
echo $dataraw[customer][phone] ;    
echo $raw[good_name];
echo "<br>";
}
```

}

Проблема в том, что он выводит слишком много одинаковых значений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно что бы значения выводились без повторений имя и тел. вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данную проблему? заранее спасибо!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так, например:

```
foreach($array[orders] as $dataraw) {   
    echo $dataraw[customer][given_name] ;
    echo $dataraw[customer][phone] ;

    foreach($dataraw[basket] as $raw = ) {  
        echo $raw[good_name];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Т.е. печатать имя и телефон во внешнем цикле, один раз на элемент, а не во внутреннем каждый раз на каждый товар.